# How to UNPIVOT while creating columns dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table below:

| Date_ID | Customer_ID | Forecast_ID | Measure_1 | Measure_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230101 | C1 | FC1 | 100 | 200 |
| 20230101 | C1 | FC2 | 110 | 210 |
| 20230201 | C1 | FC1 | 50 | 50 |
| 20230201 | C1 | FC2 | 60 | 80 |

Here is the desired output table:

| Date_ID | Customer_ID | Measure_Type | FC1 | FC2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230101 | C1 | Measure_1 | 100 | 110 |
| 20230101 | C1 | Measure_2 | 200 | 210 |
| 20230201 | C1 | Measure_1 | 50 | 60 |
| 20230201 | C1 | Measure_2 | 50 | 80 |

Is it possible to unpivot the first table while creating dynamically new columns for each Forecast_ID?

Comment: Likely with dynamic SQL. Generally this is something you do in your presentation layer *not* the SQL layer.

Comment: If you are using SQL server, then use Unpivot function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by combining pivot and unpivot:

```sql
select *
into #data
from (
VALUES  (20230101, N'C1', N'FC1', 100, 200)
,   (20230101, N'C1', N'FC2', 110, 210)
,   (20230201, N'C1', N'FC1', 50, 50)
,   (20230201, N'C1', N'FC2', 60, 80)
) t (Date_ID,Customer_ID,Forecast_ID,Measure_1,Measure_2)

declare @cols nvarchar(max)

SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(x.fc, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fc)  
from (
    select distinct quotename(forecast_id) as fc
    from #data
    ) x


declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
    select *
    from (
        select  date_id, customer_id, forecast_id
        ,   x.Measure_Type
        ,   x.measure
        from    #data d
        unpivot (measure for measure_type IN(Measure_1, Measure_2)) as x
        ) x
    pivot (max(measure) for forecast_id in (' + @cols + ')) x'
exec(@sql)
```

First you need to generate a list of unique columns which will become the pivoted columns (FC1, FC2, etc).

Then you generate the unpivoted data in a subquery and pivot it back.

Answer (score 1):

unpivot followed by pivot, no dynamic sql is necessary, eg:

```
select * from test_table
unpivot (FC for Measure_Type in ([Measure_1], [Measure_2]))_
pivot (max(FC) for Forecast_ID in ([FC1], [FC2]))_
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b7a3/22)

Comment: Dynamic SQL *is* needed - you have hardcoded `[FC1], [FC2]` rather than "creating dynamically new columns for each Forecast_ID"

Comment: ah yes if the desired output table is to be dynamic as well then the list of columns in the pivot clause would require dynamic sql. siggemannen's answer will do that, you should be warned though that such a query could run into sql server's column limit (not to mention all the other reasons you should avoid not being able to know the shape of a result without executing a query)